# Fade out SystemBar

Tags: android, user-interface

I know this question was asked about 10 times here but none of them came to a solution. I don't want to use the low light SystemBar Mode I want it completely to fade out. And this is possible! The default launcher that comes with Chinese Rockchip devices does this. (It looks like the systembar just flies away into the middle of the screen). Any (new) ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since API 17 this is directly possible, just select FullScreen Activity when developing an app with Eclipse.